# Div com largura max-content não efetua quebra de linha

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando criar um contêiner cuja largura máxima seja proporcional à usada pelo próprio texto interno (por isso, usei o `max-content`), entretanto, quando a largura da tela é menor que a própria largura da `div`, não há uma quebra do texto, visto que a div está ocupando apenas uma linha.

É possível fazer com que, de fato, a largura máxima seja proporcional ao texto interno, e, ainda assim, efetuar a quebra de linha caso a largura da tela seja menor que a largura da div?

Reproduzi, minimamente, a situação problema no código abaixo:

```css
div {
    font-size: 28px;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
}

div.com-max {
    width: max-content;
}

div.sem-max {
  font-size: 14px
}
```

```html
<p>Com o max-content: O texto fica ajustado, mas não ocorre uma quebra de linha quando o conteúdo é maior que a largura atual (a fonte maior é para dar um exemplo do problema).</p>
<div class="com-max"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eget ligula eu lectus lobortis condimentum. Aliquam nonummy auctor massa.<a href="#">link</a>.</span></div>

<br>

<p>Sem o max-content: Fica um espaço demasiado após o fim do texto.</p>
<div class="sem-max"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<a href="#">link</a>.</span></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o objetivo for limitar a div ao tamanho da tela pode experimentar o `max-width: 100vw;` que é relativo ao tamanho do view-port:

```css
.foobar {
    font-size: 28px;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
}

.foobar.com-max {
    width: max-content;
    max-width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<p>Com o max-content: O texto fica ajustado, mas não ocorre uma quebra de linha quando o conteúdo é maior que a largura atual (a fonte maior é para dar um exemplo do problema).</p>
<div class="foobar com-max"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eget ligula eu lectus lobortis condimentum. Aliquam nonummy auctor massa.<a href="#">link</a>.</span></div>
```

Comment: Ótimo, Guilherme! Muito obrigado, cara!